# Can the "-" symbol be used in naming?

Tags: java, naming-conventions

I have started java at uni, I have my notes on syntax, and have googled. Haven't, yet written a program. I have gone through my notes, googled and cannt find an answer to this.

I can find that the "-" is used as an operator in java. I can see that names are not permitted to start with a number. "_" are allowed.

What I cannot find, is the "-" symbol permitted to be used in naming classes, methods or variables in java?

eg "fat-smelly-cat"

I just want to be sure of the definitive answer

Comment: You already stated that it is an operator, so it would not make much sense to use a minus in names.

Comment: You don't have to *look* for an answer---it presents itself in the form of a compiler error message.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The [JLS #3.8](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-3.html#jls-3.8) defines what identifiers are valid: they must start with a "Java Letter" followed by zero or more "Java letter-or-digit". The two sets are defined as follows:

> - A "Java letter" is a character for which the method `Character.isJavaIdentifierStart(int)` returns `true`.
> - A "Java letter-or-digit" is a character for which the method `Character.isJavaIdentifierPart(int)` returns `true`.

`Character.isJavaIdentifierPart('-')` returns false, so the answer is no.

Answer (score 5):

No, it is not possible. You will find more information about allowed characters in the [Java specification](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-3.html#jls-3.8).

Answer (score 4):

'-' is not valid. The below snippet will give you a 'fascinating' list of characters that you can use-

```
for (int i = Character.MIN_CODE_POINT; i <= Character.MAX_CODE_POINT; i++){
    if (Character.isJavaIdentifierStart(i) && !Character.isLetter(i)){
        System.out.print((char) i + "\t");
    }
}
```

If your console cannot print the characters, try changing-

```
System.out.print((char) i + "\t");
```

To:

```
System.out.print(i + "\t");
```

Then you can see the code and find the character representations online.